# Load content into div, and resize the div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Animation - Smooth Size Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244758/jquery-animation-smooth-size-transition)

I have a div #infoMenu, whose content is being replaced with the following code:

```
function infoMenu(worldID) {
    $('#infoMenu').load('main.php?worldID='+worldID+'&menu #infoMenu').html('Loading...');              
}
```

I wonder if I can animate the div's height instead of it just "jumping" into diffrent heights depending on the new content´s space.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling this has more to do with a load callback function than animating the height.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a callback function:

```
function infoMenu(worldID) {
    $('#infoMenu')
        .load('main.php?worldID='+worldID+'&menu #infoMenu', function(data){
          $('#infoMenu').animate({ height: '500px' }, 1000);
        })
        .html('Loading...');              
}
```

But make sure the css has a set height and `overflow: hidden;`

---

Edit: Better yet, set the `overflow:scroll` then animate to the scrollHeight:

```
$('#infoMenu').animate({ height: $('#infoMenu')[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
```