# jQuery smooth resizing of element on .html()

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Animation - Smooth Size Transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244758/jquery-animation-smooth-size-transition)

I have a `div` with content that changes using `.html('some content')`. When the content changes, the height of the div either increases or decreases depending on whether the content is getting longer or shorter.

Right now the `div` resizes immediately. I want to use jQuery to make it resize smoothly, i.e. expand smoothly if the content is taller, or shrink smoothly if the content is shorter.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find the answer you are looking for on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244758/jquery-animation-smooth-size-transition with the almost exact same question.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

there's a demo script on the linked page

Answer (score 0):

jquery `animate()` function will be helpful for you here is the manual [link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)